# Is there a line limit when writing to a txt file using Java?

Tags: java, line, limit

I'm trying to keep a log of http responses with writing them in a txt file.

I'm using the FileWriter in Java, but unfortunately when the number of lines (e.g. 1000 lines) or the size of the txt file (e.g. 80kb) is exceeded, it automatically removes the previous content and writes the new ones.

This happens every time the limit is exceeded.

```
try{
    File file = new File("response.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
    writer.write(+System.currentTimeMillis()+"\t"+response+"\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();}
catch(IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("\nError");}
```

Comment: The limit on a file is generally how much disk space you have. As a note, opening, writing and closing this file for every single log operation could be really expensive in terms of performance. Can you leave that handle open and write to it as necessary?

Comment: @evag0r are you executing this code over and over for each log entry?

Comment: Yes, basically the code is executed every new request, in a while loop until the end. So I can close the file after the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
file.createNewFile();
```

Here you are creating a new file every time you call this method.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
```

Here you are trying to append to an existing file, which no longer exists because of the prior `File.createNewFile()`. So you are losing all your prior output and writing to a new file every time you call this method. Remove it.

This kind of second-guessing is always and everywhere a complete waste of time and space. `new FileWriter()` already has to do all that anyway, and you're just forcing it to happen twice: in this case, erroneously.

In fact you should try to keep the file open rather than reopening and reclosing it every time you call this method. What you're doing is horrifically inefficient. As well as not working.

NB When you get an exception, print the *exception*. Not just `"error"`. Otherwise next thing you know you will be asking here why it prints `"error"`, just because you didn't write your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's either because:

- There's not enough disk space.
- `file.createNewFile()` is being used for every line and it's not reliable.
- You open and close the stream for every line.
- You call this code in a multithreaded environment without synchronising.

Comment: It's because `File.createNewFile()` is being used every time and it *is* reliable.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
BufferedWriter out = null;
try
{
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    out.append(response);
    out.newLine();
} catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();  // if needed
    out.append("Error");
    out.newLine();
}
finally
{
    ResourceUtil.closeQuietly(out);
}
```

Comment: Try this why? Mere code is not an answer. You have to  explain.